# Wie sagt man "to preserve a language"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Bei dict.cc habe ich die zwei passenden Ausdrücke derselben Bedeutung gefunden:

> Eine Sprache konservieren.
>
> Eine Sprache bewahren.

Jedoch bin ich mir unsicher, ob sie in diesem Kontext verwendet werden können:

> Durch das Lesen der altmodischen Bücher ist die einzige Möglichkeit, eine Sprache zu bewahren.

Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: Nein, aber ich würde *das Lesen altmodischer Bücher* anstelle dessen schreiben. Ich vertue mich vielleicht.

Comment: *Altmodisch* ist wahrscheinlich das falsche Wort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich würde eher zum Begriff "**erhalten**" tendieren, weil es das Gefühl von am "Leben erhalten" mehr rüberbringt (es haucht der Sprache mehr Leben ein).

Comment: Obwohl das eine gute Übersetzugn ist, erscheint mir "Erhalten" schon fast etwas viel, wenn man zum Beispiel an Latein denkt, welches auch als "tote Sprache" beschrieben wird. Die Sprache ist dann nicht wirklich am "Leben erhalten", wenn sie tot ist?!

Comment: Interessanter Kommentar! Meiner Meinung nach kommt es auf den Zusammenhang drauf an. Ich nehme an, wenn man das Wort "altmodisch" braucht, wird dieser Satz nicht in einer wissenschaftlicher Arbeit stehen. Damit die blumige Tonalität einigermassen konsistent bleibt, würde ich deswegen "erhalten" brauchen.

Answer (score 3):

In diesem Fall ist das Wort *bewahren* richtig und besser als *konservieren*. 
*Konservieren* bedeutet etwas organisches, zum Beispiel Lebensmittel oder Körper, haltbar zu machen.
Wie c.p. und CarstenSchultz richtig angemerkt haben, solltest du Folgendes schreiben:

> Das Lesen alter Bücher ist die einzige Möglichkeit, eine
>   Sprache zu bewahren.

Edit: 
Es ist auch teilweise korrekt zu sagen "*der Bücher"* anstatt nur *"Bücher"*. Das Wort *"der"* ist bestimmt und bezieht sich auf bestimmte Bücher. Wenn du nun in einem Satz vorher zum Beispiel eine Bibliothek erwähnst, würde sich das *das Lesen der Bücher* auf die Bücher in der Bibliothek beziehen. Damit besteht Gefahr, dass sich der Sinn deines Satzes zu

> "Das Lesen der Bücher in dieser Bibliothek ..."

ändert. 
 Du möchtest dich aber auf **alle**, nicht nur bestimmte alte Bücher beziehen.

Comment: Danke! Das Lesen der altmodischen Bücher ist falsch?

Comment: Nicht umbedingt. Versteht man meine Erklärung(in Antwort editiert)?